# BS4 not changing updating values on python when they are changed on the website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The price of ETC prints correctly, just that its the price from a few minutes before. Is there anyway to make this value update as soon as it updates on the website.
Maybe a cache that needs clearing?

The price on the website is $121.70 and the program is printing $123.00 which was the price a few minutes ago

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import time

url=requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum-classic")
while True: 
    time.sleep(1)
    print((soup(url.text,"html.parser").findAll("div",{"class":"priceValue___11gHJ"}))[0].text.strip(),"\n========")
```

Comment: write `url=requests.get...` line inside `while` loop

Answer (score 1):

**Requests and BS4 doesn't cache anything.**

Did you check  the website you are **scraping**?

Everytime when the page is refreshed it loads an old value and then updates a new value. The new value is updated via AJAX. (just refresh the page and see it for yourself)

So what code does is same as refreshing the page every 1 secound in a loop.

For this kind of website you should go with [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)